# ssh2_exec password encryption

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

How can I call ssh2_exec function in php to execute a command in a remote server without hardcoding my server password?

Here's the PHP manual reference:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'myusername', 'mypasswordisvisibleforeveryone');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
?>
```

Comment: You could also do something like `ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'myusername', $_REQUEST['password'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup a user just for access from this server then user a public ssh key

You can connect like that using the following code...

```
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh, 'user', '/location/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/location/to/.ssh/id_rsa', 'passphrase');
```

where `$ssh` is your `$connection`